# Route to more than one homecontroller

Tags: asp.net-core, url, routes

I have in the controller folder like this:

```
  -Controller(Main Folder)
    -HomeController(Main Controller)
    -HomeBasic1Controller
    -HomeBasic2Controller
    -HomeBasic3Controller
    -HomeBasic4Controller
```

When I execute the program, first it´s going to `HomeController`, until here everything is correct, then in HomeController I can call to any controller, I can go to `HomeBasic1Controller` or to any other HomeBasicXController.

The problem is in the URL, it´s showing like this

> http://localhost:XXXXX/HomeBasic1

but I want to be like this

> http://localhost:XXXXX/Home

no matter from which controller is calling!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to put all your actions on the Basic1,2,3, and 4 controllers all on HomeController.  This is the generally accepted convention.  If you can't do that, then what you want is "custom routing".  The straightforward way to start this approach is to add a route for each action in Basic1 with each specific URL.  A single route might look something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Basic1SomeAction",
                "home/someaction",
                new { controller = "HomeBasic1", action = "SomeAction" }
            );
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion!

Comment: I use the code you gave to me, still the same, the url still: http://localhost:XXXXX/HomeBasic1. I want to use HomeBasic1Controller, but in the url shows  http://localhost:XXXXX/Home.

Comment: If I put the homebasic1controller in another project? i can call the project homebasic1 and the controller just homecontroller!